# Find internal energy in relation to number of mole of gas

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

I have some equation for internal energy of some gas which is function of pressure and volume, for specified number of moles in this gas, let's say $m$.
So i have: $$U(p,V)_{n=m}=..$$

Question is how do find general function which also depends on number of moles. $$U(p,V,n)$$

Comment: An ideal gas, or any gas?

Comment: Any one component gas.

Comment: So you have the same pressure and volume, but a different number of moles, and it's not an ideal gas?  Is this an actual homework problem, or just something you dreamed up?

Comment: It's real homework problem. If it's helps the $U=AV^2p$ for n=2 moles. $A$-constant

Comment: Are you given an equation of state?  Are U and V per mole?

Comment: No, and no. I use small $v$ volume per mole.